# testlink 1.9.17 DB Access error-debug_print_backtrace

Tags: testlink, sourceforge

I have installed testlink 1.9.17 with mysql5.6,still facing the below error.

```
DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ============================================================================== 
#0  database->exec_query(CREATE TABLE /*prefix*/testcase_script_links (
  `tcversion_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `project_key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `repository_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `code_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch_name` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `commit_id` varchar(40) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tcversion_id`,`project_key`,`repository_name`,`code_path`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8) called at [D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\testlink\install\sqlParser.class.php:98]
#1  SqlParser->process(sql/mysql/testlink_create_tables.sql) called at [D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\testlink\install\installNewDB.php:445]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded your mysql, try this command in shell, then install testlink:

```html
mysql_upgrade -p
```